# Problema con biblioteca "Text" en Unity

Tags: unity2d

El problema que tengo ahora, es que en mi juego quiero hacer un contador de puntos que se muestre en un texto en pantalla, pero al hacer el script, me da el error:

> (Type UnityEngine.UI.Text does not contain a definition for Text'
>   and no extension method Text' of type UnityEngine.UI.Text' could be
>   found. Are you missing an assembly reference?)

Pero al incluir un `using UnityEngine.UI.Text`, me aparece este otro error:

> (A using directive can only be applied to namespaces but
>   UnityEngine.UI.Text' denotes a type. Consider using a `using static'
>   instead).

Si pueden ayudarme, les agradecería muchísimo.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public enum  GameState{Idle, Playing, Ended, Ready};//estados del juego

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    [Range (0f, 0.20f)]//rango de velocidad dentro de unity
    public float parallaxSpeed = 0.02f;//velocidad inicial
    public float scaleTime = 6f;//cada sierta cantidad de tiempo dado
    public float scaleInc = .25f;//incrementar
    public RawImage fondo;
    public RawImage plataforma;
    public Text pointText;
    public GameObject uiIdel;
    public GameState gameState = GameState.Idle;//estado por defecto, parado
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject enemyGenerator;

    private AudioSource musicPlayer;

    private int points = 0;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        musicPlayer = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        bool userAction = Input.GetKeyDown("up") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);

        //empieza el juego
        if (gameState == GameState.Idle && userAction){//teclado arriba o mouse izquierdo respectivamente
            gameState = GameState.Playing;//pasar de estado "Idle" a "Playing"
            uiIdel.SetActive(false);
            player.SendMessage("UpdateState", "PlayerRun");
            player.SendMessage("DustPlay");
            enemyGenerator.SendMessage("StartGenerator");
            musicPlayer.Play();
            InvokeRepeating("GameTimeScale", scaleTime, scaleTime);//cada 6 seg llama al scaletime, y luego se repetira cada 6 seg
        }

        //juego en marcha
        else if(gameState == GameState.Playing){
            Parallax();
        }
        //juego preparado para reiniciarce
        else if(gameState == GameState.Ready){
            if (userAction){
                RestartGame();
            }
        }
    }

    void Parallax(){
        float finalSpeed = parallaxSpeed * Time.deltaTime;//Adapta velocidad segun el ordenador
        fondo.uvRect = new Rect(fondo.uvRect.x + finalSpeed, 0f, 1f, 1f);//velocidad del fondo
        plataforma.uvRect = new Rect(plataforma.uvRect.x + finalSpeed * 4, 0f, 1f, 1f);//velocidad de la plataforma
    }

    public void RestartGame(){
        ResetTimeScale();
        SceneManager.LoadScene("principal");
    }

    void GameTimeScale(){
        Time.timeScale += scaleInc;//incrementa la velocidad dependiendo del tiempo dado anteriormente
        Debug.Log("Ritmo Incrementado: " + Time.timeScale.ToString());
    }

    public void ResetTimeScale(){
        CancelInvoke("GameTimeScale");
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        Debug.Log("Ritmo Incrementado: " + Time.timeScale.ToString());
    }

    public void IncreasePoints(){
        pointText.Text = (++points).ToString();
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por lo que he visto en https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html la propiedad text es en minusculas. Asi que quiza tu problema se resuelva cambiando en tu metodo IncreasePoints el texto pointText.Text = (++points).ToString(); a pointText.text. Echale un vistazo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres modificar el texto de un objeto de la clase `Text` debes utilizar la propiedad `text`. Tu problema está en que estás utilizando `Text` (Con la T mayúscula, que hace referencia a la clase `Text`) en vez de la propiedad `text` en la siguiente línea:

```
public void IncreasePoints(){
   pointText.Text = (++points).ToString(); // <------
}
```

Bastaría con cambiar la propiedad `text` a minúsculas:

```
pointText.text = (++points).ToString();
```